# Is it possible to work for free in Aerospace Industry for experiences

Tags: aircraft-manufacturer, aerospace, engineer

I am currently in a master's Aerospace Engineering program and are trying to buff up my resume by having some experiences. I heard that in IT industry, there are ways for new programmers to earn experiences by work for free for big IT companies. Is the same method also possible for aerospace industry? Like is it even possible to phone a company and say "Hi, I am a masters Aerospace Eng student and are looking for experiences, could I work as a Engineer-In-Training for free or just as a simple technician so I can get some experiences?"

Comment: What country are you looking for work in?  There's legal aspects of unpaid vs paid that vary by country, and some variation in typical job opportunities by country.

Comment: @CodyP I live in Canada

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. What you're looking for is called an [internship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internship), and they're hardly limited to just IT work.

Since most internships are targeted specifically at students looking for experience, they're usually coordinated through the school. So, your first step would probably be to contact your professors/advisor/etc. to see what opportunities are available (and to see if they think you can handle working in addition to your course load). If that doesn't pan out, you can look for internships just like you would any other job, via websites and phone calls.

Comment: All the interns I’ve worked with got paid.

Comment: @Jim There are also paid internships. Most people I've talked to had the unpaid type, but I've never been in any kind of internship myself, so I can only report what I've researched.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted care to explain why?

Comment: Not my DV for what it’s worth.